# spark-submit dependency conflict

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to submit a jar to spark but my jar contains dependencies that conflict with spark's built-in jars (snakeyml and others).

Is there a way to tell spark to prefer whatever dependencies my project has over the jars inside /jar
**UPDATE**

When i run spark-submit, i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:540)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:501)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:132)
... 41 more
```

which is caused by spark having an older version of validation-api (validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar)
My project has a dependency on the newer version and it does get bundled with my jar (javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile)

I submit using this command:

```
/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true
```

but i still get the same exception

Comment: Hi there, did you find the solution?

Comment: I have not ....

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your jar using SBT, you need to exclude those classes which are on the cluster. For example like below:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
```

You are doing that by adding "provided", that means these classes is provided already in the environment where you run it.

Comment: I don't want to exclude the dependencies, i want spark to use the newer one bundled with my jar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if using SBT, but I used this in build.sbt via assembly as I had also sorts of dependency conflicts at one stage. See below, maybe this will help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i'm using maven, it's spring boot application

Comment: There should be some equivalent I would expect. Success

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by setting the following confs to true:

```
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with 2 jars, and this is what I ended up doing, ie copied the required jars to a directory, and used the extraClasspath option

```
spark-submit   --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath="C:\sparkjars\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\sparkjars\gson-2.8.6.jar" myspringbootapp.jar
```

From the documentaion, spark.driver.extraClassPath  Extra classpath entries ***to prepend to the classpath*** of the driver.